# Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#

```
        usersIncome = InputOutput.DisplayTaxDue(double userIncome, double taxDue, double taxRate, double flatRate);
        Console.WriteLine(" Your income is : {0:C} ", usersIncome );
        Console.WriteLine(" Your tax due is : {0:C} ", taxDue);    
        Console.WriteLine(" Your income is : {0} ", taxRate );
        Console.WriteLine(" Flat Rate is : {0} ",  flatRate);
```

I am getting invalid token after every open and closing parenthesis.

Comment: You don't need type names before the arguments being passed to `DisplayTaxDue()`.

Comment: For one, `double userIncome, ...` is invalid syntax. You don't respecify the type when you pass a parameter.

Comment: Did you write this code inside a method, or directly in your class?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you wrote this code directly inside a class; instructions can only appear in a method, not directly in a class:

```
class YourClass
{
    public void YourMethod()
    {
        usersIncome = InputOutput.DisplayTaxDue(userIncome, taxDue, taxRate, flatRate);
        Console.WriteLine(" Your income is : {0:C} ", usersIncome );
        Console.WriteLine(" Your tax due is : {0:C} ", taxDue);    
        Console.WriteLine(" Your income is : {0} ", taxRate );
        Console.WriteLine(" Flat Rate is : {0} ",  flatRate);
    }
}
```

Also, when you call a method, you don't specify the types of the arguments; they're already specified in the declaration.